# How can I recv TCP socket data in one package without dividing

Tags: c++, sockets

Since I create a TCP socket,it is fine when  sending  small amount data.no fragment. all  data came in one package. but when data becomes bigger and bigger. TCP package has been divided  into pieces.. it`s really annoying. Is there any option to set on socket, and the socket will automatically put pieces into one package for me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a byte stream.  All the bytes will arrive correctly and in the right order, but not necessarily when you want them.  If you need to send anything more complex than one byte, you need another protocol on top of TCP. That's why there are all those other TCP/IP protocols like HTTP, SMTP etc.

Comment: +1, though these are not "IP protocols", but "application-layer protocols".

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov - right, I should have written 'TCP/IP protocols' - will edit..

Comment: Additionally, all those protocols have extra signalling/control data associated with them, which provides un-necessary overhead.. (in addition to TCP's own signalling)

Comment: @mnunberg - sadly, yes, but we're stuck with them :(

Answer (score 1):

No there is not.  There are even situations where you might receive 1 byte.

Comment: devices in the network can fragment... packets in a stream can take different paths at different times changing fragments... the way you receive data won't line up with fragments leaving you differing levels of buffered data.  in short, anything can (and will) go, down to a byte.

Answer (score 1):

TCP provides you *reliable bi-directional byte stream*. It takes care of sequencing, transport-layer packetization, retransmission, and flow-control. Decades of research went into optimizing its performance. Pretty nifty. The small price you pay for all this convenience is that you have to *write and read the stream in a loop*, watching for a complete [*application protocol*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) message you can process when receiving, and flushing yet unbuffered bytes when sending.

Comment: +1, this issue is getting right up there with 'FP compares do not work' and 'why do I get a segfault from my complex function full of arrays with its huge collection of single-char 'i,j,k,l,m' indexes'.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using higher level messaging libraries like [ZMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/). It handles all the message packing and unpacking for you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to socket programming!

I'll chime in here and say that there's pretty much nothing you can do to solve you issue without adding extra dependencies on libraries which handle application protocols for you. There are some lower level message packing libraries (google's protocol buffers, among others) which may help.

It's probably the most beneficial to get used to reading and writing TCP data in a loop. It's proven and very portable.. even if you pay a small price in actually writing the streaming codecs yourself.

Try it a few times. It's a useful experience which you can re-use, and it's really not as difficult and annoying once you get the hang of it (like anything else, really).

Furthermore, it's fairly easy to unit-test (rather than dealing with esoteric libraries and uncommon protocols with badly/sparsely documented options)..

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize sockets reads to return larger chunks, on platforms that support it, by setting low watermark using  `setsockopt()` and `SO_RECVLOWAT`. But you will still have to handle the possibility of getting bytes less than the watermark.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `SOCK_SEQPACKET` (or possibly `SOCK_RDM`). See [socket(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html).

Comment: While in theory it's something nice to use for local communication (i.e. it's "guaranteed" to be reliable (unlike unix datagram sockets)), it's probably not a good choice for on-the-wire communication